# Display bar / line graph in Titanium

Tags: titanium

i want to display bar or Line graph can any one help how to achieve it in titanium.
Any good example or link for this
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You can use RGraph Library. With this library you can make graphs in HTML(`webView`) in Titanium. For implementation you can check [Link1](https://gist.github.com/bob-sims/1428481#file-app-js) and [Link2](http://www.rgraph.net/docs/api.html).